# Benefits of Machine Learning over Regression

Tags: machine-learning

I have deployed a contact strategy some time back based on a random forest model. The campaign did very well. Now how do I attribute the performance of this campaign to machine learning? That is how do I quantify the benefit of using machine learning over traditional modelling techniques such as logistic regression.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If the campaign is for increasing conversions/signups, it can be assessed directly by seeing if the contact strategy created using random forest gave higher conversions or not compared to the existing logistic regression model.